# If $(H,\pi)$ is a finite dimensional irreducible representation of a C*-algebra $A$, then $\pi(A)=B(H)$

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $(H,\pi)$ an irreducible representation such that $\dim(H)<\infty$. Then how do I show that $\pi(A)=B(H)$?

> Here is what I tried: Since $(H,\pi)$ is irreducible, we know that $\pi(A)'=\mathbb{C}1_{B(H)}$ (*cf.* Murphy, Theorem 5.1.5), where $\pi(A)'$ is the commutant of $\pi(A)$. Hence $\pi(A)''=B(H)$. Furthermore, I know that $\pi(A)$ is norm-closed in $B(H)$, since $B(H)\cong M_{\dim(H)}(\mathbb{C})$ is finite-dimensional and $\pi(A)\subset B(H)$ is a vector-subspace.

I think that I have to implement Neumann's double commutant theorem somewhere. This theorem says that a $*$-algebra $N$ acting on $H$ (and $1_{B(H)}\in N$) is strongly closed if and only if $N''=N$ (*cf.* Murphy, Theorem 4.1.5). Also, I don't see how I can relate the strong closure and norm closure of $\pi(A)$.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every finite-dimensional subspace of a topological vector space is closed, hence $\pi(A)$ is strongly closed.  Using this, you have everything you need to finish the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But the strong topology is weaker than the norm topology. Hence strong closed implies norm closed. Not the other way around, I think.

Comment: The strong topology and norm topology on $B(H)$ coincide when $H$ is finite-dimensional.  In fact, there is a unique vector topology on any finite-dimensional vector space.